# Is it possible to pass generic type as generic parameter?

Tags: typescript

Just pass generic type like a `callback`:

```js
type FUNC<ARG,RET, F> = (arg: ARG) => F<RET>;
type PROMISE<T> = Promise<T>;
type IDENT<T> = T;
type A = FUNC<number, void, IDENT>;
type A_PROMISE = FUNC<number, void, PROMISE>;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please share more detail about your question.

Comment: Why would this possible? The type system only exists at compile time and is completely removed at runtime. If you pass a generic **type** "as a callback" what exactly are you going to *call* when the types are removed during compilation?

Comment: @VLAZ Why not? It is just compile time type calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment. There was a discussion back in 2014. See this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).

---

If your intention is to constraint the return type, you may:

```js
type FUNC<ARG,RET extends Promise<any>> = (arg: ARG) => RET;
```

To get back the wrapped type, you may:

```js
type PromiseType<T> = T extends Promise<infer T> ? T : never

type A = Promise<string>
type B = PromiseType<A> // string
```