# "Pass" generic type to another generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

Anything new since : [Is it possible to pass generic type as generic parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983160/is-it-possible-to-pass-generic-type-as-generic-parameter)  ?

My specific problem :

This work fine

```js
type isArrStr<T extends readonly string[] > = T extends readonly["str"] ? true :false ; //dummy 
type _retAny<T> = any 

//***************
type wrapper<T>  = any extends _retAny<isArrStr<infer I>>  ? T extends I ? isArrStr<T> : never :never
//********
let myVar:wrapper<readonly["str"]> //ok , return true 
let myVar_1:wrapper<readonly["ll"]> //ok , return false
let myVar_2:wrapper<string> // ok , return never
```

But this doesn't

```js
type wrapper<F,T>  = any extends _retAny<F<infer I>>  ? T extends I ? F<T> : never :never //error : Type 'F' is not generic 
//********
let myVar:wrapper<isArrStr,readonly["str"]> //error : Generic type 'isArrStr' requires 1 type argument
//let myVar_1:wrapper<readonly["ll"]>
//let myVar_2:wrapper<isArrStr,string>
```

Do you know something to overcome this difficulty ? Thanks for your help have  nice day

I'm trying to reproduce HighOrderFunction behavior with type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's still not possible to pass a generic to a generic type parameter ***plainly***, however, it's allowed to pass one if it's constrained. I think, this approach might work for you -

```ts
type isArrStr<T> = T extends readonly ["str"] ? true : false; //dummy 
type _retAny<T> = any;

type Args<M extends Fn> = M["args"];

type Fn<Args = unknown, Return = unknown> = {
    args: Args;
    return: Return;
}

type Apply<F extends Fn, U extends Args<F>> = (F & { args: U })["return"];

interface IsArrayOfStr extends Fn {
    return: isArrStr<Args<this>>
}

type Result = Apply<IsArrayOfStr, readonly ["str"]>; // true
type Result1 = Apply<IsArrayOfStr, readonly ["11"]>; // false
type Result3 = Apply<IsArrayOfStr, string>; // false
```

Note that an interface is used to declare the function because the extension of types is limited and instead, an intersection is done for types. Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgzgQQE5IMrCQHgCoD4oC8U2UEAHsBAHYAmcUSEAhjQPZUA2IUA2gERwMfALpQA-FAwBXaAC4oAMyYc4EANxQA9JppSAtnu4AoUJCgB9RsARUQOfESa21Rk+GjIA5nEwBZUhTUdFAAYlQOUL78TEjeIi5uZmGYXvREUlQA1lSsAO5UADRQAEoQwFJIVIRQGdl54dUA3kZQrVAx3vKpLm0MZRVU8qXllS4Avq6mHmBgXJghAZS09GFFAKqLQfSp87gRABQLAGRQje2xcPIbYwCU-FYD8a4wVJRISgDG0ACSiChMIAA8gp0EhNstQlVmr0HpV5PBkGgMCkLphgAALeB7IwTRLQUpwKQcYDVBAzOa-REA4GgoqMFjsLi8ARCYS4DTaSRIGR4koQQnEgCMpPJdkp-yBIIwdOYbE43H4gsFInZWk0imUql5BKJwAAzCLZmK-khqVKkEVBEgXp5VZylCoIEA) to the playground.

Comment: Thank you so much , I hope you have a wonderful day !

Comment: A few libraries attempt to standardise this. [free-types](https://github.com/geoffreytools/free-types) currently supports type constraints, [hotscript](https://github.com/gvergnaud/hotscript/pull/104) is experimenting with them. I wonder if there are other libraries.

Comment: @issueWebpack if my answer helped you solve the problem you were trying to solve and you're satisfied with it, consider marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score -1):

Use a helper type to pass generic type correctly:

```
type isArrStr<T extends readonly string[]> = T extends readonly ["str"] ? true : false;
    type _retAny<T> = any;
    type ExtractGenericParam<F> = F extends (arg: infer U) => any ? U : never;

type wrapper<F, T> = any extends _retAny<F<infer I>> ? T extends I ? F<T> : never : never;
let var: wrapper<isArrStr, readonly ["str"]>; // Returns true
let var_1: wrapper<isArrStr, readonly ["ll"]>; // Returns false
let var_2: wrapper<isArrStr, string>; // Returns never
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help and the time you took to respond to my concern, good day.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: It didn't work but I'm still fairly new to typescript which explains it ,however several people guided me towards the marvelous solution of @0xts .

Comment: This is not valid Typescript. A type constructor must come with its parameters. The solution given by @Oxts is the current state of the art for working around this limitation. You can also use an interface as a map from keys to types and have the interface pass its type parameters to the inner types, but it is less flexible and more awkward to use